# Underlined text gets crossed in firefox

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Underlined in post text gets crossed in firefox. Css says underlined, and all the other browsers are fine. Just firefox

Link here
http://soloveich.com/pr6/acupuncture/

At the bottom of the page.

Comment: on hover also issue fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code on your photo's text tag `<span style="font-size: x-large; text-decoration: underline;">Photos:</span>` and avoid the above `span` tag's `text-decoration` ...

**OR**

please remove/change to *{vertical-align:bottom;} instead of *{vertical-align:top;}

It will be work fine !!!

Comment: @shell - please give me upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using span tag please use inline css in anchor tag.
like below mentioned; And it will solve the problem. The other solution written above will double the underline which looks more awkward.

here you can use the code.

```
<a href="?page_id=228"style="font-size: x-large; text-decoration: underline; 
color:#888888;vertical-align:bottom;"><span >Photos:</span>
</a>"
```

Regards,
Kheema